# Please be understanding, I am new to this. Can some please explain the verify function?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void limit(int stop)
{
    int x;

    for(x=0;x<=100;x=x+1)
    {
        printf("%d\t",x);
        if(x==stop)
        {
            printf("You Won!\n");
            return;
        }
    }
}

int verify(int check) /*this part*/
{
    if(check<0 || check>100)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    int x;

    printf("Enter a stopping value(1-100): ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if(verify(x))/*this part too*/
    {
        limit(x);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is out of range.\n",x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know how the verify function works. The parts I do not know are commented. How do the verify function verify if the input value is within the range? The verify function returns FALSE which is 0 when it is out of range but how is it use?

Comment: You need to talk to your TA or read the related chapters in the book.

Comment: ^^^ it's difficult to imagine a simpler function and call.  You need to learn more basic stuff than we can reasonably teach you on a Q&A site for professonal and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: What's a TA? I know this is some ugly ass code and people here are smart but please. I really want to learn. I've been stuck on this for an hour.

Comment: What don't you understand? `||` is a logical or, `<` is less than and `>` is greater than.

Comment: Well, it's not ugly, really.   It's just... well.. already very clear what it's doing.  You don't need to be smart to understand it, just a bit more experienced and knowledgeable.

Comment: You need to learn how if work : With TRUE `if ( 1 ) { // This execute }` With FALSE `if ( 0 ) { // this does not } else { // but this does }`

Comment: @Colin__s I understood that. It returns 0, right? What does 0 do to the if else statement in the main function?

Comment: I mean, limit() is more complex, and if you understand that, it's difficult to see how you can not get verify().

Comment: That "turns into" `if(0)`, which is false, so the code in the `if(verify(x)){}` block doesn't execute, and the code in the `else{}` does execute.

Comment: @kaldoran if value = 1 then it is true? Is 1 a value that means execute?

Comment: I understood limit function.  just want to know if 0 as an argument mean false universally?

Comment: Try Googling for 'C boolean expressions'

Comment: @LeonardoDonatello `if(verify(x))` means `if(verify(x) != 0)`

Comment: Well, it's saying if x is between 0 and 100 then limit(x). Which given it says input 1-100 you might want to change the 0 to 1

Comment: @WeatherVane if(0) means it will do the else statement? Thats all i wanna know.

Comment: it returns FALSE (ie: don't do it) if less than 0 or more than 100

Comment: @LeonardoDonatello that is correct.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the  `int` number are lower than `0`, let's say `-3` it's out of range, also if the number are higher than `100`, lets say `104` the function will return false.

Let's say enter `104` wich is not in the specified range the `verify` function will get that number, check if either the number are lower than `0` or higher than `100`. In our case the number is higher than `100` and the verify funtion will return `FALSE`.

In the `if(verify(x))` you will have a false if-statement because the verify function returned that. We will go directly to the `else` statement and do the code in there.

If you select a number that is in range, for example `33` the verify function will return `TRUE` and the if-statement in your `main` will be `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks dude. I understood that. I just want to know. FALSE is defined 0 right? If it is returned(0) to the if else statement, it should not execute? That means 0 is 'do not execute';

Comment: Yes, in C there are no boolean values, such as `FALSE` or `TRUE` but you have defined `FALSE` as `0` and `TRUE` as `1`. `0` in C will always mean false and that is not `0` will be true, in your case `1`.

You could also write `#define TRUE 3` and it would generate the same result, but 1 is way more convinient.

0 in a if-statement will mean "dont do any of the stuff in this if-statement" and if you have a else-statement it will du the stuff in the else statement